# Sum of a record source in access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that has the following display:

type  $ value 
1        5   
1         3  
1         2  
2         1   
2         3

This query is the record source of my form I would like the form to display the data as so

type  Sum of value 
1         10   
2          4   
is there a vba or setting way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do that is to use an [aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194423.aspx) function in your query, in your case it would be [sum](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php). Your query will look like this.

```
SELECT Type, SUM(value) As Total FROM table GROUP BY Type;
```

if you use the graphical query builder then you will have to follow [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-data-by-using-a-query-b84cdfd8-07ba-49a7-b067-e1024ccfcca8)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I know about this function But I am trying to find a way around it because I need the unsummed data for something else and generating a second query just for the sums is going to be very time consuming (there are 1000s of records)

Comment: the SUM function is extremely fast, I have seens access databases with 30000+ records and it executeds really fast. Any VBA code will be several order of magnitude slower that what you can do with a query